# Constraining date selection in JCalendar

Tags: java, swing

How can I restrict what dates can be selected in [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/) ? In particular, I want to make it impossible to select any date before today's date.

Comment: Can you elaborate? With an example if possible.,.. Other wise this is just a downvote magnet...

Comment: @Thihara I am making project using java swing, for that i am using NetBeans IDE 7.3.in that i create one java project, after creating new java project i have create one package in it and take Jpanel in that package. after all this stuff i have took one Jcalender and put JPanel.this run properly,but i want to disable previous date in that Jcalender

Comment: What do you mean by disable previous date? Do you want that no date that is before today can be selected?

Comment: yes. User cant select date before system date.

Comment: for example i want to select date for product bill.for that i click on calender, now in that calender i cant select previous date. this is my requirement.

Comment: what is this jcalender? Are you talking about JCalender? Can you add it as a tag?

Comment: But i cant fullfill my requirement using that question

Comment: Which JCalendar are you referring to?  Is it [this one](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/)?

Comment: Aleks . yes i use this one

Comment: @stonedsquirrel, indeed, it is.

Comment: I don't think it supports setting the minimum date.  You can only set the minimum year using `jcal.getYearChooser().setStartYear(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR))`